# docker: how to show the diffs between 2 images

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile with a sequence of RUN instructions that execute "apt-get install"s; for example, a couple of lines:

```
RUN apt-get install -y tree
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

After having executed "docker build", if I then execute "docker images -a", I see the listing of all the base-child-child-.... images that were created during the build.

I'd like to see a list of all of the packages that were installed when the "apt-get install -y git" line was executed (including the dependent packages that may have also been installed, besides the git packages).

Note: I believe that the "docker diff" command shows the diffs between a container and the image from which it was started. Instead I'd like the diffs between 2 images (of the same lineage): the "tree" and "git" image IDs. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Have a look at :

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-diff

This tool can diff local or remote docker images and can do so without requiring docker to be installed. It has file as well as package level "differs" (for example: apt, npm, and pip) so that you can more easily see the differences in packages that have changed between two docker images.

Disclaimer:  I am a contributor to this project

Comment: Does it compare image SHA256 or image digest ?

Comment: It doesn't show a file added by a pre/post-install scripts.

Answer (score 29):

This one worked for me:

```
docker run -it e5cba87ecd29 bash -c 'find /path/to/files -type f | sort  | xargs -I{} sha512sum {}' > /tmp/dockerfiles.e5cba87ecd29.txt
docker run -it b1d19fe1a941 bash -c 'find /path/to/files -type f | sort  | xargs -I{} sha512sum {}' > /tmp/dockerfiles.b1d19fe1a941.txt
meld /tmp/dockerfiles*
```

Where e5cba87ecd29 and b1d19fe1a941 are images I am interested in and /path/to/files is a directory which could be "/".
It lists all files, sorts it and add hash to it just in case. And meld highlights all the differences.

Comment: I like this this neither has too much state, nor requires other tools.

Comment: Well, it requires your image to contain `find`, `sha*sum`, etc.

Comment: With "-it" you get CRLF line endings from TTY, see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8513 . The simple "docker run image cmd" works just as well and also provides correct unix-style line endings.

Comment: @Huckle even alpine contains find and sha512sum

Answer (score 19):

I suppose you could send both images' file systems to tarballs via `docker export CONTAINER_ID` or `docker save IMAGE_ID` (updated based on comments)

Then use whatever tool you like to diff the file systems - Git, Rdiff, etc.

Comment: `docker export` takes a container id as a parameter, not an image id

Comment: `docker save` is for images

Comment: Just for clarity, in your example it should be `docker export CONTAINER_ID`

Answer (score 18):

It is now 2019 and I just found a useful tool which was released in late 2017.
https://opensource.googleblog.com/2017/11/container-diff-for-comparing-container-images.html

The following content is from [container-diff](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-diff) github page:

```
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=history  [History]
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=file  [File System]
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=size  [Size]
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=rpm  [RPM]
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=pip  [Pip]
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=apt  [Apt]
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=node  [Node]
```

You can similarly run many analyzers at once:

```
container-diff diff <img1> <img2> --type=history --type=apt --type=node
```

Comment: Hey that's very useful, thx :)

Answer (score 17):

Each RUN instruction creates a new container and you can inspect what a container changed by using `docker diff <container>`.

So after building your dockerfile, run `docker ps -a` to get a list of the containers the buildfile created. It should look something like:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE        COMMAND               CREATED        STATUS ...
53d7dadafee7  f71e394eb0fc /bin/sh -c apt-get i  7 minutes ago  Exit 0 ...
...
```

Now you can do do `docker diff 53d7dadafee7` to see what was changed.

Comment: Thanks this works, although I have to use a container and it's not ideal: I cannot use the -rm option in my builds or if at some later point I rm the containers to cleanup, then the info is lost. It'd just be great to be able to diff 2 related images: "docker diff base_image base_grandchild"

Answer (score 10):

If you know container ID or name (even stopped container),
you can quickly dump file list on-the-fly.

```
$ docker export CONTAIN_ID_OR_NAME | tar tv
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0           0  2  6 21:22 .dockerenv
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0           0  2  6 21:22 .dockerinit
drwxr-xr-x  0 0      0           0 10 21 13:46 bin/
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0     1021112 10  8  2014 bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0       31152 10 21  2013 bin/bunzip2
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0           0 10 21  2013 bin/bzcat link to bin/bunzip2
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 10 21  2013 bin/bzcmp -> bzdiff
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0        2140 10 21  2013 bin/bzdiff
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 10 21  2013 bin/bzegrep -> bzgrep
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0        4877 10 21  2013 bin/bzexe
......
```

Then you can save list to file and compare too list files.

If you insist to use image ID or name, you can dump **first layer's file list** on-the-fly:

```
$ docker save alpine |tar xO '*/layer.tar' | tar tv
drwxr-xr-x  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/ash -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/base64 -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/bbconfig -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0      821408 10 27 01:15 bin/busybox
```

After all, i suggest you start the container then stop it, then you can get a merged file list as described in first way.

2017/02/01: **The fastest way to show container's file list, you are free to enter its root dir to read files**:

```
# PID=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' CONTAIN_ID_OR_NAME)
# cd /proc/$PID/root && ls -lF
drwxr-xr-x  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/ash -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/base64 -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx  0 0      0           0 12 27 06:32 bin/bbconfig -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x  0 0      0      821408 10 27 01:15 bin/busybox
```

Note, if you are using docker-machine, you need first enter it by
`docker-machine ssh` then `sudo sh`.

Now you get the root dir of the two container, you can use diff to compare them directly.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at:

https://github.com/moul/docker-diff

They list `Brew` install instructions for Mac, I'm assuming it's a Bash script, so I assume it could be made to work in other *nix environments.

Comment: Nice tool. FYI, it's basically running the containers, exporting to tarball, and diff-ing the file list.

Answer (score 7):

A new dedicate d command is available, starting with [`docker scout`](https://docs.docker.com/scout/) and [Docker Desktop 4.17](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/) (March 2023).

Also: [`nerdctl` v1.7.1 (Nov. 2023)](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/releases/tag/v1.7.1) has implemented `nerdctl diff` (see last part of this answer).

---

[Docker Desktop 4.18](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4180) now includes [`docker scout compare`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/scout_compare/) (still [early access](https://docs.docker.com/release-lifecycle/#early-access-ea)). It can compare two images and display packages and vulnerabilities differences.

```bash
docker scout compare --to IMAGE|DIRECTORY|ARCHIVE IMAGE|DIRECTORY|ARCHIVE
```

Examples:

> Compare an image to the latest tag
>
> ```bash
> docker scout compare --to namespace/repo:latest namespace/repo:v1.2.3-pre
> ```

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FtDw7paXwAYoUAu?format=jpg&name=small]

---

`nerdctl diff` is done through [PR 2626](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/pull/2626) from [Min Uk Lee -- `minuk-dev)`](https://github.com/minuk-dev), after [issue 1376](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/issues/1376)

> Inspect changes to files or directories on a container's filesystem
>
> Usage: `nerdctl diff CONTAINER`

Comment: can we use this to compare two remote images on ECR I ran docker login  before I ran docker scout but running in to `ERROR   Status: please login using Docker Desktop or 'docker login' command: no credential found for "index.docker.io", Code: 1`

Comment: @saketh What does `docker credential inspect index.docker.io` show you?  If the username and password are incorrect, you can update them with `docker credential set index.docker.io username password`

Comment: doesn't aws ecr get-login-password | docker login set that?

Comment: `docker: 'credential' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'`

Comment: @saketh What version of Docker are you using? (I confirm credential is not a native command). All I can think of is the possibility of wrong credentials when you used `docker login`.

Comment: Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996

Comment: @saketh Looks recent enough. And the credentials stored in `~/.docker/config.json` look correct?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like in this case maybe you only needed to see the diff between two layers. If so, [`dive`](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive#dive) is awesome for this; it lets you inspect the filesystem at each layer and you can filter files by change type (unchanged, added, removed, modified).

And if you want to inspect the differences between two unrelated images, having two `dive` processes running side by side works okay too.

Comment: Agree! it's pretty slick. I wish pkgdiff one day can show the same.
https://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/