# Diff docker registry images

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Recently the centos images in the global docker registry were updated (~4 days ago it seems). Before the update, I could successfully build off of the Centos 6 image but now I have some installation errors for some packages. When I look at the images from before and after, and then attempt to follow version history it looks something like

```
f1b10cd84249 -->  b9aeeaeb5e17 (originally worked)
             \->  fb9cc58bde0c -->  a005304e4e74 (current version where my code breaks)
```

where the arrows show how the image was updated (left is oldest while right is newest). I'm curious as to how the images are different. Is there anyway to do a `diff` of the `a005304e4e74` and `b9aeeaeb5e17` images?

Comment: possible duplicate of [docker: how to show the diffs between 2 images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200304/docker-how-to-show-the-diffs-between-2-images)

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried, but I guess you could do:

```
$ docker export -o f1.tar b9aeeaeb5e17
$ docker export -o f2.tar a005304e4e74
$ diff <(tar -tvf f1.tar | sort) <(tar -tvf f2.tar | sort)
```

Export will create a tar of the filesystem, which we then use to get a diff of the file differences. (I got the diff syntax from [Diff between two .tar.gz file lists in liunx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156383/diff-between-two-tar-gz-file-lists-in-liunx) )

You might find just running `docker history` on the images gives you enough information though.